# How can you log a request/response to a log4j logger in Camel?

Tags: java, log4j, apache-camel

Let's say you have a Camel route, and you want to print the entire request to a log4j logger.

```
from("direct:myroute")
  .id(routeName)
  .process(new HttpProcessor(endpoint))
  .marshal()
  .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, MyRequest.class)
  .toF("http://%s", "myroute")
  .unmarshal()
  .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, MyResponse.class);
```

You can print a trace to a logger by adding this:

```
.to("log:mylog?level=debug")
```

...but that just prints a meta log that describes the transaction.  You can print the entire JSON request to a file by adding this:

```
.to("file:myfolder")
```

...but that will print one file per request to a special folder.  Is there any way to have Camel print the entire request to a log4j logger?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy

```
.from("foo:bar")
 .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG,"${body}");
```

You can also play with the options on the more powerful logger that you have been using so far to enable/disable various features. What you need to set kind of depends if you deal with files or streams or plain strings etc.